# Try to install the vagrant-hostmanager

Tags: installation, vagrant

Im trying to install vagrant-hostmanager and suddenly this error appears and i have no clue why.
Would be nice if someone can help me!

im using Vagrant 1.6.5 and this is the errormessage:

```
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb 
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/eike/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/eike/.vagrant.d/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

would be nice if someone can help me :-)

Comment: are you on windows ? if so can you run the command as admin

Comment: No sry, im on ubuntu and : 
sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager dont work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it complains about a missing native library `zlib`

on ubuntu, you can install with `sudo apt-get install zlib` and you should be fine to reinstall the plugin

Comment: it works! thanks and how do you know why i should download this ? is there a hint or something?

Comment: in the error log, it said `zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2` and I know by experience that nokogiri uses native libraries (when you failed a few times, after you remember :))